# Compare and calculate the average of two different images in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have two `480x640` images `A` and `B`. I want to compare them where each pixel in `A` will be compared to the same pixel in image `B` and  then the result of this pixel will be put in `C` in the same pixel position (where the result is only 0 or 1, 0 incase they don't have the same value, and 1 incase they do have the same value. So `C` will be a `480x640` matrix containing only 0's and 1's. So if anyone could please advise how this can be done in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for single-channel images:

```
C = bsxfun(@eq, A, B);
```

As @Daniel points out, for multi-channel (color) images you'll want to add `all` for each pixel:

```
C = all(bsxfun(@eq,A,B),3);
```

Comment: `all(bsxfun(@eq,A,B),3)` for colour images

Comment: @Daniel Good catch, I was thinking grayscale images all the way. I'll update.

Comment: Why even use `bsxfun`? Just go with: `C = A==B` or `C = all(A==B,3)`

Comment: @knedlsepp Ha, true! It does seem like overkill. :)